# How do I replace all strings found with a regular expression with itself concatenated with another string?

Tags: c#, regex

For example, my regular expression found the string: `some\file\path.xml` and I want it to be changed to `new_root\some\file\path.xml`. Is there a way to do this using the regex replace method? If not, what is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you can do what you are asking using Regex.Replace.
Check out [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) article on MSDN.

Example:

```
var path = @"C:\some\file\path.xml";
var result = Regex.Replace(path, @"(C:\\)(.*)", "$1new_root\\$2");
```

Result is C:\new_root\some\file\path.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that, just find the string you want with a buid-in function and concatenate with what you want.

For a more general search/replace you can do this:

```
  string pattern = @"(?>\w+\\)+\w+.xml";
  string replacement = "new_root\\$0";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Comment: They don't say they were searching for that literal string. It could have been a more complex pattern that found that.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear, but I am looking for multiple strings of that form